# How to attach pages or tabs from One Power BI file to another

Tags: powerbi

How to attach pages or tabs from One Power BI file to another. I have two Power Bi Projects and I would like to add the pages from one to the other. Is there a way to achieve this without affecting the measures, calculated columns and data sources?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is some way to improve manual work, provided that you have the same measures* and columns in both reports.

1. Go to source report, click on a page but mind not clicking on any visual, select all visuals (Ctrl + A), copy (ctrl + C),
2. Go to destination report, add a blank page,
3. PASTE (ctrl + V), ha, not that easy - it won't work. You need a hack!
4. Add a whatever empty visual, like a table, or a card.
5. PASTE (ctrl + V), it will work now.
6. Remove the empty visual of point 4.

You can omit point 3.